# Radio buttons in Angular Material Forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I'm trying to make a form inside a `mat-grid-list` that has radio buttons, but while the data hooks up to my formControl properly the display is completely messed up with the label not getting tied into the material form.
What I want it to look like:
[Desired Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkBZd.png)
[Current Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaOhB.png)

Here is the html, I removed the extra inputs for readability. I tried butting the section inside `<mat-form-field>` but that completely broke the form.

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z3 search-form">

    <mat-grid-list [cols]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 1 : 3" rowHeight="80px">

        <form [formGroup]="searchForm">

            <mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                    <input formControlName="name" id="inputName" matInput title="name" type="text">
                </mat-form-field>
            </mat-grid-tile>

            <mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-label>Builder Group Status</mat-label>
                <mat-radio-group aria-label="Builder Group Status" formControlName="status" id="inputStatus">
                    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let stat of status" [value]="stat">
                        {{stat}}
                    </mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
            </mat-grid-tile>

        </form>

    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

ts file, again removed the extra fields for readability:

```
status: string[] = ["Suspended", "Active"];

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      status: new FormControl("Active", Validators.required),
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<mat-grid-tile>
  <div>
    <mat-label>Builder Group Status</mat-label> <br />
    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Builder Group Status" formControlName="status" id="inputStatus">
      <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let stat of status" [value]="stat" style="margin: 10px;">
        {{ stat }}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```